# "My probation ends this Friday." What tense to use and why?

Tags: tenses

What tense is correct to use?

1. My probation ends this Friday.
2. My probation is ending this Friday.
3. My probation will end this Friday.

Thanks.

Comment: All three are fine and, in context, mean the same thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 are correct.

As for the third one, you want to use **is going to end this Friday** as it's something already planned.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with #3 either.